# permissions and user with no group

Tags: php, apache, apache2

i have created a user with no group to launch the apache service on a windows system, and to my surprise it can launch httpd.exe even though there is no security setting set for this user in the directory, or ANY directory, is it best practice to assign a group to this user, if so then which? (using local, no network, lowest permissions possible to be able to run the service)

so how do i set the default for a user that has no group? and what is the best group to run a user service account for apache using the lowest permissions possible to be able to run the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Apache as service. I recommend reading this guide. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html